# Laravel Eloquent assigning to a model attribute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Id like to overwrite a relationship attribute like the following:

```
$article['tags'] = $article->tags->pluck('title');
return compact('article');
```

It fails because it returns the tags attribute as an array of objects instead of an array of title strings. The API consumer needs the data in that form. This also reduces the size of the payload.

My current work around is to add another attribute and unset the original one.

```
$article['tagged'] = $article->tags->pluck('title');
unset($article['tags']);
return compact('article');
```

But I wish it was simpler and straightforward.

Comment: try `$article['tags'] = $article->tags()->pluck('title');`

Comment: Why not you just return `title` from tags relation instead ?

Comment: @Sohel0415 yours is the simple answer. Maybe add it below for me to accept?

Comment: @TechyTimo ok, i will add, thanks

Comment: @C2486 That yields an error - return $this->hasMany('App\Tag')->pluck('title'); // must return a relationship instance. Please provide your example as an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the relation method `tags()` to get the `title` array.

```
$article['tags'] = $article->tags()->pluck('title');
```

Answer (score 1):

For overriding use [`setRelation(key, value)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L695):

```
$article->setRelation('tags', $article->tags()->pluck('title'));
```

^ This assumes you didn't preload the relationship. If you did, just remove the parenthesis from `->tags()` (same as in your question: `->tags->pluck('title')`).

For unsetting a single relationship, there's no available method. You could use `->setRelations(array)` though.